# HttpWebRequest.Proxy=null rewrite Expect100Continue

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I found crazy behavior of HttpWebRequest class when u set HttpWebRequest.Proxy=null. At first time it rewirte Expect100Continue to true for some reason. For example this code

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        webRequest1.Method = "POST";

        webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest1.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy(); ;
        Console.WriteLine(webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue);

        webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest1.Proxy = null;
        Console.WriteLine(webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue);


        webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        webRequest1.Method = "POST";

        webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest1.Proxy = null;
        Console.WriteLine(webRequest1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue);


        HttpWebRequest webRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        webRequest2.Method = "POST";

        webRequest2.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest2.Proxy = null;
        Console.WriteLine(webRequest2.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

will write:
True
False
False
False

And only one way i found to resolve this:

```
        var Expect100Continue = webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue;
        webRequest.Proxy = null;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = Expect100Continue;
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `Proxy` property on a `WebRequest`, `ServicePoint` will be recreated.

The value of `Expect100Continue` will default to whatever the value is set on the `ServicePointManager` that can be configured from the app.config file.

At least, this is what I can see from looking at the disassembly.